# Diffeomorphism of the sphere

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm given the following function. I'm trying to see that it is a diffeomorphism.

Let $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$. Consider $f: S^2 \rightarrow S^2$,

$ f_{\theta}(x,y,z) = (x\cos((1-z^2)\theta) - y\sin((1-z^2)\theta)), x\sin((1-z^2)\theta) + y\cos((1-z^2)\theta), z)$

Note that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

I'm trying to figure out if this is a diffeomorphism. I know the definition. I'm having a few problems.

I think it's pretty clear intuitively this map is continuous and differentiable - all its components are sums, differences, products etc. of continuous and differentiable functions. I also think it's pretty clear this function is injective, by looking at the restriction condition as requiring the variables to be implicitly a function of the others.

Surjectivity I'm not sure I see, but maybe I can figure something out there....

The real problem for me is the continuous and differentiable inverse. I have no clue how to find it. Can anyone lend me a hand with the conditions?

Or maybe it's not a diffeomorphism for one of these reasons. I'm trying to figure out intuitively if it is or not, because it's going to be ugly on the notation to prove some of these things, and I don't want to bark up the wrong tree. It doesn't help that because this is either a family of functions of three variables or (possibly worse) a function of four variables, I'm really just overwhelmed by it.

Comment: It looks like a diffeomorphism to me. The simplest way to show it's a diffeomorphism is to write down the inverse. You just have to reverse the sign of $\theta$, or something like that. That gives another homeomorphism which is also smooth. So it's a diffeomorphism both ways. A lot of practical proofs that maps are diffeomorphisms are most conveniently done by writing down the inverse explicitly, if that is feasible, which it clearly is here.

Comment: I guess that's what I don't get. Why does changing the sign on $\theta$ give an inverse?

Comment: Without actually writing this all out in full, it looks to me like you are simply doing a $z$-dependent rotation of each latitude line of the sphere. So the inverse of a rotation is the corresponding rotation with the opposite angle. In other words, if you replace $1-z^2$ with $z^2-1$, and compose these two transformations, you should get back to where you started. If you follow a single longitude line like $\theta=0$, you should see that it is distorted into a curve of some kind. If you are using radians, then it looks like the rotation at the equator is 1 radian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your map in cylindrical coordinates:
$$
x = \sqrt{1-z^2} \cos \phi\\
y = \sqrt{1-z^2} \sin \phi
$$
and, if you call $\rho = \sqrt{1-z^2}$,
$$
f_\theta = (\rho\cos\phi\cos(\rho^2\theta) - \rho\sin\phi\sin(\rho^2\theta)), \rho\cos\phi\sin(\rho^2\theta) + \rho\sin\phi\cos(\rho^2\theta), z) = (\rho\cos(\phi+\rho^2\theta),\rho\sin(\phi+\rho^2\theta),z)
$$ 
which, it is apparent, is rotating each slice of the sphere by an angle depending on $z$ in a continuous way. Also the angle is $0$ for $z=\pm 1$.

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates! Great idea. I need to go back and revisit my calculus III days. Re-learn all the useful facts about coordinate systems if I'm going to study manifolds seriously.